# JavaFX ProgressBar Wont Reset

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar

I am making a program that patches some files and I wanted to use a `ProgressBar` as progress indicator, however the progress bar stays completely full and won't reset after it's finished.
This is the method that updates it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < paths.getItemCount(); i++)
{       
     current_progress += 0.02; 
     System.out.println("verifiing: " +paths.getItems()[i] );
     File bugger = new File(paths.getItems()[i]);

     File dst = new File(starmade_path + "\\data\\image-resource\\ " +  names.getItems()[i] );
     Files.copy(bugger.toPath(), dst.toPath(), REPLACE_EXISTING, COPY_ATTRIBUTES, NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
     ProgressBar.setProgress(current_progress);  
}
```

I already tried this

```
for(int i = 0; i < paths.getItemCount(); i++)
{        
    current_progress += 0.02; 
    System.out.println("verifiing: " +paths.getItems()[i] );
    File bugger = new File(paths.getItems()[i]);

    File dst = new File(starmade_path + "\\data\\image-resource\\ " +  names.getItems()[i] );
    Files.copy(bugger.toPath(), dst.toPath(), REPLACE_EXISTING, COPY_ATTRIBUTES, NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
    ProgressBar.setProgress(current_progress);  
}

ProgressBar.setProgress(0);
```

But when I use this it won't display any progress at all.
`Thread.sleep()` won't do it either.

Comment: You shall post full code to make us able to detect where is the problem.

Comment: The most likely cause is that you are not using multithreading correctly, but unless you [edit] your question to include a [MCVE], no-one can really know.

Answer (score 0):

1. dont write code like this 'ProgressBar.setProgress' , this syntax should be reserved for static calls using the class.

make your objects like

```
ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
```

or

```
@FXML
ProgressBar progressBar;
```

2.
This loop works

```
float current_progress = 0f;     
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  {
            current_progress += 0.02;
            progressBar.setProgress(current_progress);
        }
```

and the progress bar progresses to 20% of the width, so your code is syntactically correct, possibly the issue is the paths.getItemCount() max value is too small to see some meaningful progress, check your output for "verifiing: " +paths.getItems()[i] for this

Comment: Yes it seems that it acutally goes to fast, is there a way to make this method slower ??

Comment: see Path Transitions in this link  https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/javafx/javafx-animation-example/